# How to stop populating data in the disabled textbox field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to stop binding the data while the textbox is disabled. once i click the left side checkbox the value gets empty and the textbox gets disabled. But if i type any number on the parent textbox than the value gets populated in the disabled textbox.

here is the code below

```
//data populate for tier1 globally
        $("#txtPercentofTier1").on("change", function (e) {


            $('.txtDataPopTier1').val($(this).val());

            $('#txtPercentofTier1, #txtPercentofTier2').change(computeHead);
            $("#txtOON").val($('#txtPercentofTier1, #txtPercentofTier2').change(computeHead));


        });
        $("#txtPercentofTier1").on("keyup", function (e) {


            $('.txtDataPopTier1').val($(this).val());
            $('#txtPercentofTier1, #txtPercentofTier2').change(computeHead);


        });

        //data populate for tier2 globally
        $("#txtPercentofTier2").on("change", function (e) {
            $('.txtDataPopTier2').val($(this).val());
            $('#txtPercentofTier1, #txtPercentofTier2').change(computeHead);

            $("#txtOON").val($('#txtPercentofTier1, #txtPercentofTier2').change(computeHead));

        });
        $("#txtPercentofTier2").on("keyup", function (e) {


            $('.txtDataPopTier2').val($(this).val());
            $('#txtPercentofTier1, #txtPercentofTier2').change(computeHead);
           
        });
```

[image]

Comment: `if( !$(selector).is('[disabled=disabled]') ) { //populate }`

Comment: can you please elaborate little bit.

Comment: To check your input element, you need to look for the `disabled` property @DotNet Coder. If you are not creating a statement around that. A disabled property is only disabled for user interaction. It can still be changed programmatically, which is what you are experiencing. You there need to say "if my input field is NOT disabled", then populate my field(s).

Comment: the `is()` function basically returns a boolean, true or false. So if you check for the propery disabled, and it exists, the `is()` function will return true, because it exists, the field is disabled. We there want to say if it is NOT disabled, then populate the field(s), which is why we put the `!` operator in front.

Comment: still the problem is not solving. the code i used below
 if (!$('.txtDataPopTier1').is('[disabled=disabled]')) { //populate 

                $('.txtDataPopTier1').val($(this).val());
            }

Comment: It should work. Could you please replicate the functionality in a snippet that we can run? It would speed up the process immensely.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is due to you not checking that the input field is disabled before setting the value. It doesn't matter if the input field is disabled or not, you can still programmatically update it. Disabled essentially only applies to the person physically (trying) to type into the input.

```js
$('#disabled').on('change', (e) => {
  const bool = $(e.target).is(':checked');
  $('#input2').attr('disabled', bool);
});

$('#input1').on('keyup', (e) => {
  const input2 = $('#input2');
  if (!input2.is(':disabled')) { // <- check to see if input is disabled
    input2.val(e.target.value);
  }
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
<label for="disabled">Disable</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="disabled" />
```

Comment: what will happen if i have 5 textbox with same class name. than how can i find which textbox is disabled or not under same class?

Comment: You can set things up to handle that. `$.closest` would help in this scenario to figure out what row it's in.

Comment: can you please give an example?